# Why cant I see my for Each loop in the preview view in XCode

Tags: xcode, core-data, foreach, swiftui, swiftui-list

I am making a to do list to learn about Core data. I noticed when I add a `ForEach` loop to read my core data entries, it stops loading the view and the app crashes. If I replace the `ForEach` loop with a `Text("Hi")`, it all works. However the app runs perfectly in simulator.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @FetchRequest(fetchRequest: ToDoItem.getAllToDo()) var toDoItems:FetchedResults<ToDoItem>

    @State private var newTodoItem = ""

    @State private var selection = 0

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Section (header: Text("Whats... next")) {
                    HStack{
                        TextField("New Item", text: self.$newTodoItem)
                        Button(action: {
                            let toDoItem = ToDoItem(context: self.managedObjectContext)
                            toDoItem.title = self.newTodoItem
                            toDoItem.createdAt = Date()

                            do {
                                try self.managedObjectContext.save()
                            }catch {
                                print(error)
                            }

                            self.newTodoItem = ""
                        }){
                            Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                                .foregroundColor(.green)
                                .imageScale(.large)
                        }
                    }
                }.font(.headline)
                Section(header: Text("To Do's")){
                    ForEach(self.toDoItems) {todoItem in
                        HStack{
                            VStack(alignment: .leading){
                                Text(todoItem.title!)
                                    .font(.headline)
                                Text("\(todoItem.createdAt!)")
                                    .font(.caption)
                            }
                        }
                    }.onDelete {indexSet in
                        let deleteItem = self.toDoItems[indexSet.first!]
                        self.managedObjectContext.delete(deleteItem)

                        do {
                            try self.managedObjectContext.save()
                        }catch {
                            print(error)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("My List"))
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Any idea what the issue is?

Comment: Break content view on smaller subviews

Comment: @Asperi Thanks for your comment. Initially I had the `ForEach` loop in a separate view and I had the same error so that's why I decided to have it all in one view to make sure the preview provider is not causing it.